# I want to replace Nan values with row averages but first column( first value in the row) is a string

Tags: python, fillna

I want to replace Nans with the averages of the rows but the first value of the row is a string and therefore python can't calculate the row averages( axis=1) . How can I replace Nans with row averages and keep the first value as the name for that row?

```
Index    Country   1990 1995 2000 2005 2010 2015 
 0         US       5    6    Nan  9    19   11
 1        Germany   5    Nan  3    7    19    9
 .         ...      ..    ..   ..  ..   ..   ..
 ,         ...      ..    ..   ..  ..   ..   ..
```

I use something like this `df.fillna(df.drop['country'] , axis=1).apply(lambda x: x.mean() ,axis=1)`.
It doesn't replace Nans as fillna is not working. I don't have a problem replacing Nans with axis=0.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I've rolled back the edit you appear to have submitted over the top of a good one, and fixed a formatting error. Keep an eye on the preview with the next question you submit - most active users will look at your question only once and if it looks messy they may just ignore it, vote it down, or vote for it to be closed.

Comment: Thank you man. I'm new to this and I will do better next time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `data.csv` would be like this:

```
x,y,a,b,c,d
0,"A",1,2,3,4
1,"B",5,6,7,
2,"C",9,,11,
```

It looks like you were after something like this:

```
from pandas import read_csv

df = read_csv('data.csv')
print(df)

df = df.apply(lambda x: x.fillna(x[2:].mean()), axis=1)
print(df)
```

Output:

```
   x  y  a    b   c    d
0  0  A  1  2.0   3  4.0
1  1  B  5  6.0   7  NaN
2  2  C  9  NaN  11  NaN
   x  y  a     b   c     d
0  0  A  1   2.0   3   4.0
1  1  B  5   6.0   7   6.0
2  2  C  9  10.0  11  10.0
```

It works because of the way the lambda ignores the first two columns:

```
x.fillna(x[2:].mean())
```

And it is applied row by row, so along axis 1.

Note: Pandas decides to make the columns that have `NaN` floating point data and keeps the other integer type. Of course there's ways to fix that, but I decided to keep the answer simple.

Comment: You're welcome, see you for the next one :)